# Missing thick vertical line when using multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, line, vertical

For some reason couple of the thick vertical lines are missing from the first row (still there is the thin line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Review of methods and ...}
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c?c|c?c|c|c|c|c?c|c|c|}
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Bugs' info} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Expertise info}         & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Based on} \\
    \hline
    Method & \parbox{1.7cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Title + description} & \parbox{0.8cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Meta} & \parbox{1.9cm}{\linespread{0}\selectfont{}\centering Bug fixing; title / description} & \parbox{1.6cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Being a committer} & \parbox{1.1cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Tossing history} & \parbox{0.8cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Meta} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Changed code} & \parbox{1.6cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Final committer} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Closer / resolver} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Drafted assignee} \\
    \hline
    AA & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    BB & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    CC & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{adjustbox}
  \label{tab:previousMethods}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you replaced the `?` spec by a `|` by using  `\multicolumn{2}{c|}` I assume you intended `\multicolumn{2}{c?}`

Comment: unrelated to the vertical rule but `\linespread` and `\centering` do nothing in a `c` cell as that is horizontal mode like `\mbox`

Answer (score 2):

I propose this other layout, with rows and columns switched, and less horizontal and vertical rules. The `caption` package is loaded to ensure a decent vertical spacing between table and caption above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66}
  \caption{Review of methods and ...}
  \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}
  \begin{tabular}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}llccc!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}}
    \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{2}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}c}{Method} & AA & BB & CC \\
    \specialrule{0.6pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}l !{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}}{\bigstrut\em Bugs info} \\
      & Title +description & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
      & Meta & & & \checkmark \\
    \specialrule{0.6pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}l !{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}}{\em Expertise info}\\
    & \makecell[l]{Bug fixing;\\ title/description} & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
      & Being a committer & & & \\
      & Tossing history & & & \checkmark \\
      & Meta & & & \checkmark \\
      & Changed code & & & \\
    \specialrule{0.6pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}l !{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width2pt}}{\bigstrut\em Based on} \\
      & Final committer & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
      & Closer/resolver & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
      & Drafted assignee & & & \\
    \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:previousMethods1}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For more space around cells content use `cellspace` package and for column headers `makecell` from `makecell` package:

In preamble of your MWE add:

```
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
```

and change columns definitions and columns headers to:

```
   \begin{tabular}{|Sc?c|c?c|Sc|c|c|c?c|c|c|}
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{2}{Sc?}{Bugs' info}
       & \multicolumn{5}{c?}{Expertise info}
       & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Based on} \\
    \hline
    Method & \makecell{Title +\\ description} & Meta
           & \makecell{Bug fixing;\\ title /\\ description}
           & \makecell{Being a\\ committer}
           & \makecell{Tossing\\ history}
           & Meta
           & \makecell{Changed\\ code}
           & \makecell{Final\\ committer}
           & \makecell{Closer /\\ resolver}
           & \makecell{Drafted\\ assignee} \\
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this makes the top and bottom margins much better, but also increases the spacing between lines (e.g, between "Bug Fixing" and "Title"). The idea is that this was just an MWE and the real table was so bigger. So I needed to shrink from all 4 sides.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David_Carlisle for his constructive comments:

I changed `\multicolumn{2}{c|}` to `\multicolumn{2}{c?}`
and changed `\multicolumn{5}{c|}` to `\multicolumn{5}{c?}`

Here's the answer (note that I also added a vertical thick line for more clarity):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.66}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Review of methods and ...}
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c?c|c?c|c|c|c|c?c|c|c|}
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{2}{c?}{\centering Bugs' info} & \multicolumn{5}{c?}{Expertise info}         & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Based on} \\
    \hline
    Method & \parbox{1.7cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Title + description} & \parbox{0.8cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Meta} & \parbox{1.9cm}{\linespread{0}\selectfont{}\centering Bug fixing; title / description} & \parbox{1.6cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Being a committer} & \parbox{1.1cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Tossing history} & \parbox{0.8cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Meta} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Changed code} & \parbox{1.6cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Final committer} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Closer / resolver} & \parbox{1.3cm}{\linespread{1}\selectfont{}\centering Drafted assignee} \\
%     \hline
    \Xhline{6\arrayrulewidth}
    AA & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    BB & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    CC & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\\hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{adjustbox}
  \label{tab:previousMethods}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to love horizontal rules that touch the contents…

Comment: @Bernard, I even commented \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}, but still the three line title (e.g., "Bug Fixing; ..." is touching the lines (top and bottom). Any ideas (other than removing the horizontal lines)?

Comment: You can use `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}` (or `3pt`). Also since you load `makecell`, `\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells` inside the `table` environment.